# $\ln(x)=ax^4$. Find a value for $a$ such that the function has only one real root.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

**Question:**

> $\ln(x)=ax^4$. Find a value for $a$ such that the function has only one real
>   root.

How do i go about this kind of exercises? It is for a multiple choice exam for college admission so i only need the reason behind it in order to be able to solve such exercises. I tried plotting the graphs but I cant tell.

Comment: Are we assuming $a > 0$.  Other wise $a = 0$ will yield $\ln x = 0$ has only one solution.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the figure below

[image]

the curvature of $ax^4$ is always positive and that of $\ln x$ is always negative (by twice differentiating them) therefore they intersect in exactly one point if they are also tangent in that point i.e.$$\ln x=ax^4\\\dfrac{1}{x}=4ax^3$$which leads to $$ax^4={1\over 4}$$ and by substituting we have $$\ln x=\dfrac{1}{4}$$which yields to $$x=e^{1\over 4}$$and $$a=\dfrac{1}{4e}$$also the case $a\le 0$ is trivial since for $a=0$ the only answer is $x=1$ which is valid and for $a<0$ the functions $\ln x$ and $ax^4$ are strictly increasing and decreasing respectively.

Comment: What if $a \le 0$?

Comment: This is the trivial case since for $a=0$ the only answer is $x=1$ which is valid and for $a<0$ the functions $\ln x$ and $ax^4$ are strictly increasing and decreasing respectively.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Obviously, $x>0$. $\ln x=ax^4$ could be rewritten as $$a=\frac{\ln x}{x^4}.$$ We want to find the range of $a$ such that $y=a$ and $y=f(x)=\dfrac{\ln x}{x^4}$ intersect at only one point.

Notice that $$f'(x)=\frac{1-4\ln x}{x^5}.$$ Let $y'=0$. We have $x=e^{\frac{1}{4}}.$ Morover, $f'(x)>0$ when $x<e^{\frac{1}{4}}$ and $f'(x)<0$ when $x>e^{\frac{1}{4}}.$ Thus, we may claim that $f(x)$ increases over $(0,e^{\frac{1}{4}}]$ and decrease over $[e^{\frac{1}{4}},+\infty].$ Futher, $f(x) \in (-\infty,\dfrac{1}{4e}]$ and $f(x) \in (\dfrac{1}{4e},0)$. Here, you should notice $$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^4}=\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}\frac{1/ x}{4x^3}=\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}\frac{1}{4x^4}=0.$$

Now, we may obtain that the range of $a$ we want is $(-\infty,0]\bigcap\{\dfrac{1}{4e}\}$. Otherwise, there exist either two or none intersetion.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually understand the reason behind such exercises but I could not figure how to start it. I got confused because a was not separated from x and could not understand why. Thank you very much, again, and everyone else who has commented.

Comment: Not at all. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the function
$f(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x^4}$ and use calculus.
Use that 
$$f'(x)=\frac{1-4\ln(x)}{x^4}$$

Comment: don't you mean $f'(x)=\frac{1-4ln(x)}{x^5}$

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to show that the function $\ln x-ax^4$ has at most a single extremum, at $x=\dfrac1{\sqrt[4]{4a}}$.

For any $a\le0$, there is no extremum and a single root, as the function goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

If $a>0$, the value at the extremum is

$$\frac14\ln4a-\frac14$$ and is zero for $4a=e$, forming a double root.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a >0$.

Considering the U/valley shape of the graph of $ax^4$ and the slouching slug shape of $\ln x$ it's clear that the graphs either never intersect and $\ln x < ax^4$ for all $x> 0$.  Or they touch once and there is one solution to $\ln x = ax^4$ or the cross and recross and there are two solutions.

Now to solve $\ln x = ax^4$ is to solve $h(x) = ax^4 - \ln x = 0$ and as $a^4 \ge \ln x$ (the graphs touch once and never cross) then $h(x) = 0$ is local minimum.

So $h(x) = ax^4 - \ln x = 0$ and $h'(x) = 4ax^3 - \frac 1x =0$.  Then later becomes $4ax^4 - 1 = 0$ and notice both $ax^4 - \ln x = 0$ and $4ax^4 - 1=0$ have terms pertaining to $ax^4$.  And we can solve $ax^4 = \frac 14$.

So $\frac 14 - \ln x = 0$ and $\ln x = \frac 14$ and $x = e^{\frac 14}$.

Plugging that in we get $a*e - \frac 14 = 0$.

Which gives us $a = \frac 1{4e}$

If $a =0$ then $\ln x = ax^4 = 0$ and $x = 0$ is the onlys solution.

If $a < 0$.  Well, look at the graphs.  The U valley is upside down and *every* value intersect the slouching slug exactly once.  So $a \in (-\infty, 0]\cup \{\frac 1{4e}\}$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} 
\ln x&=ax^4
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
-4\ln x&=-4ax^4
,\\
\ln(x^{-4})&=-4ax^4
,\\
x^{-4}\ln(x^{-4})&=-4a
.
\end{align}

Let $\ln(x^{-4})=u$, then 
$x^{-4}=\exp(u)$
and we arrive at an equation

\begin{align}
u\exp(u)&=-4a
,
\end{align}

which has a well-known 
closed-form solution in terms of 
[Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

\begin{align}
\operatorname{W}(u\exp(u))&=\operatorname{W}(-4a)
,\\
u&=\operatorname{W}(-4a)
,\\
\ln(x^{-4})&=\operatorname{W}(-4a)
,\\
x^{-4}&=\exp(\operatorname{W}(-4a))
,\\
x&=\exp(-\tfrac14\cdot\operatorname{W}(-4a))
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

The number of real solutions to \eqref{1}
is defined by the number of 
real solutions to \eqref{2},
which in turn, is defined by the argument of $\operatorname{W}$,
and it is well-known 
that we have a single real solution
when the argument of $\operatorname{W}$
is either non-negative, or is equal to 
$-\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}}$.

That is,

\begin{align}
1)& -4a\ge0\quad\to\quad a\le0
;\\
2)& -4a=-\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}}
\quad\to\quad
a=\tfrac1{\mathrm{4e}}
\approx 0.09196986
.
\end{align}

In the last case we have

\begin{align}
x&=\exp(-\tfrac14\cdot\operatorname{W}(-\tfrac1{\mathrm{e}}))
=\exp(-\tfrac14\cdot(-1))
=\sqrt[4]{\mathrm{e}}
.
\end{align}